# TFS 2010 WorkItem Client - Method not found exception

Tags: wcf, tfs-sdk

I have deployed a custom TFS eventpoint to our production webserver. The server does not have the TFS sdk installed so I had to find and bin deploy all dependant dlls. For some reason, when the application tries to contact TFS using the TFS client, it is thrown a missing method exception only on the server. Does anyone know how to get this web service running on a system without installing the full SDK?

The bin deployed TFS dlls

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll

The Exception

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.HandleUnauthorizedException(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException)'.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.HandleComException(Int32 hr)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.DatastoreClass.ConnectEx(String connectionString, String defaultCachePath, String instanceId, String userSamName, String userFriendlyName, String userSid, WorkItemServer clientService)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.InitializeInternal()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ITfsTeamProjectCollectionObject.Initialize(TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore..ctor(TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection)
```

Comment: Which DLLs have you copied so far? you'll probably find that the dlls your dependent on requires others.

Comment: *Why* would you not just install the full SDK?

Comment: @Betty I've updated the question with the dlls.

Comment: @EdwardThomson This is a production web server. IT does not want to install the SDK because they want to limit effecting any other application running on the box. Also, they do not want to install extra code that might increase the security surface area of the server.

Comment: You may also need `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.dll ` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Client.dll`.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I cannot find those dlls. Those references do not exists in my add reference dialog.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Do you know where the full SDK lives? I've found http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/TfsSdk but it does not appear to have a link for just the SDK.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no SDK-only install for the .NET SDK - the smallest install is the Team Explorer install:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656.

Comment: @Phil Try looking in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0

Comment: @Betty That folder does not exist on my system, I dont have VS 2012 installed. I looked under VS 2010 and did not see that folder either.

Comment: VS 10.0 is vs 2010...  just try search the whole vs 2010 directory for "TeamFoundation" it's all i did and got a bunch of dlls

Answer (score 0):

Looks like partly connected to that problem:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/02/13/10392771.aspx

unfortunately I'm still unable to locale where to find proper version of "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll" library.

Comment: I've create blog post about my problem. You can find it below: http://mariuszgorzoch.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/method-trygetrowset-not-found/